# Configure automysqlbackup on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, database-backups, mysql-backup

I have run automysqlbackup on my Ubuntu server. Now, I want to configure it to backup database at least two times a day on times I set by myself. Currently, it is backing up all the databases every day at 6:30am. Please help me how to set it up!

Answer (score 2):

Automysqlbackup is very nice tool, it works "out of the box", but it make only one mysqldump per day, and store it 7 days (and also makes backups weekly and monthly).

You can put additionaly to /etc/crontab entry about "automysqlbackup", but if you re-run "automysqlbackup" second time in one day, it will overwrite previous backup from this day.

If you need to have history of backups with all 2 backups per day, you need to create your own backup script (for example using automysqlbackup with different credential like separate backup directory).